# Multiple 'for' loops in the same LESS file

Tags: javascript, css, less

I'm trying to create 'for' loops using LESS to output styling for different colors.

I currently have two loops that should output different styling, but only only one 'loop' runs.

Variables

```
@brands: zorg onderweg geld persoonlijk vrijetijd wonen najeleven;

// Define our variable, add extension for our color variables   
.define(@var) {
  @brand-color: '@{var}Color';
  @brand-shadow: '@{var}Shadow';
  @brand-hover: '@{var}Hover';
}
```

The first loop:

```
.buttons-loop() {
    // Loop through all the variables and output colored CTA buttons
    .for(@brands); .-each(@name) {
        // After loop happens, it checks what brand is being called
        .define(@name);

        // Output Example: .zorg .cta (:hover, :active)
        .@{name} .cta {
            background: @@brand-color;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 0px @@brand-shadow;

            &:hover {
                background: @@brand-hover;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 0px @@brand-shadow;
            }

            &:active {
                background: @@brand-shadow;
            }
        } // @{name} .cta
    } // .for(@brands)
}

.buttons-loop();
```

The second loop:

```
// Loop through all the variables and output colored meta tags
.meta .theme { 
    .for(@brands); .-each(@name) {
        // After loop happens, it checks what brand is being called
        .define(@name);

        // Output Example: .meta .thema.zorg
        &.@{name} {
           color: @@brand-color;

            a {
                color: @@brand-color;
            }
        } // @{name} .cta
    } // .for(@brands)
}
```

When both loops are in the document, only the first (buttons)loop runs, the meta-tag loop doesn't run. If I add the 'html' tag as wrapper in the buttons loop:

```
.buttons-loop() {

    html {
        // Loop through all the variables and output colored CTA buttons
        .for(@brands); .-each(@name) {
           ..
   
        } // .for(@brands)
    }
}
```

Both loops will run, but the buttons loop with output `html .brandColor .cta` which works, but feels like a hack.

Am I forgetting something or isn't it supposed to work like this?

Comment: See https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md#multiple-loops-in-same-scope

Comment: And please reduce the usage of redundant escaping. (E.g. `@brands: ~"zorg" ~"onderweg" ...;` should really be just `@brands: zorg onderweg ...;` etc.).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Hi there! Thanks for creating the 'for' loop first of all. I've tried added & { } instead of the HTML tag but that doesn't seem to work. Could you give me some pointers? The issue seems to be that the loop doesn't run in a class, because the first class is the one generated by the loop(?)

Comment: I fixed it by using the parent & selector. Ill postmy answer shortly

Comment: Hmm, yes I guess I missed the `.buttons-loop` is expanded into the global scope and this makes the first `.for` to appear there as well and then this (after certain Less version) suppresses any further `.for`s  in any scope because its auxiliary hidden mixin at global scope overrides its own instances elsewhere (well, in details it's quite tricky). In short, yes, the code in your answer is the best way to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this particular issue by using the 'parent &' selector.

```
.cta {
    // Loop through all the variables and output colored CTA buttons
    .for(@brands); .-each(@name) {
        // After loop happens, it checks what brand is being called
        .define(@name);

        // Output Example: .zorg .cta (:hover, :active)
        .@{name} & {
            background: @@brand-color;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 0px @@brand-shadow;

            &:hover {
                background: @@brand-hover;
                box-shadow: 0 3px 0px @@brand-shadow;
            }

            &:active {
                background: @@brand-shadow;
            }
        } // @{name} .cta
    } // .for(@brands)
}
```

Comment: You can ( and should in this case) accept your own answer ;).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Will do, need to wait two days ;)